# Поиск файлов по нескольким расширениям

Tags: java

Есть папка загрузки.
Ее нужно пройтись циклом по нескольким расширениям
Например,

String[] array          = new String[] {".gzip", ".zip", ".rar", ".tar.gz", ".7z", ".tgz"};

Файлы которые будут иметь расширения с массива должны будут добавлены в массив (имена файлов)
Проблема заключается в том что я могу найти все файлы только одного расширения, а вот нескольких - нет

```
File folder = new File(this.downloads);
         files = folder.list(new FilenameFilter() {
             @Override
             public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
                 return name.endsWith(".zip"); // нужно нескольких
             }
         });
```

Comment: Вы цикл написать не можете? Тогда вам не в форум, а в книжку.

Comment: писал я циклы и не раз, не получалось

Comment: Тогда пишите циклы до тех пор, пока не получится. Без циклов никуда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File folder = new File(this.downloads);
files = folder.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
            for (String format : array) if (name.endsWith(format)) return true;
            return false;
    }
});
```